# <input type="number"> working in Chrome but not on Cordova app. Samsung device using KitKat

Tags: android, html, cordova, samsung-mobile, galaxy

I found this weird behaviour in Cordova:

I have created two apps, one simple HTML 5 app and a Cordova app that runs on Samsung (S5 and Tab Pro 10.1", running KitKat), that use .

It is weird that I can see the decimal point in the keyboard when I use the WebApp (on Chrome) but it doesn't appear using the Cordova app. What's going on here and who is the causer here...

Comment: Use <input type=“tel”>